# ExpandableRecyclerView with GridLayoutManager , Expanding Parent View Vertically

Tags: android

Actually i have created a Expandable RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager with 2 span count, so whenever i click on the Parent-view of the 1st column  the child view is expanding just next to parent-view i.e horizontally and replacing the adjacent Parent View but i want to expand it vertically just below to the parent View, but when column 2nd item is clicked then there is no space next to it so it is expanding below of it . but i want to expand each parent vertically.
I have already set up the span Size for child View 2 and for parent View 1 
i am using the library 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'
please help

Comment: can you show us your code? thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: @GastónSaillén: below is the link of App: https://github.com/Rajnikant17/MyProject-3.                                                     
 plz help..Thanks

Comment: @GastónSaillén:please help.